# Skipping shouldInterceptRequest when it is a post request on the WebView of a prelollipop device?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Is there a way to know whether the request is a `POST` request when `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, final String url)` is called on prelollipop devices?

My issue basically is that I can not change the `POST` request but I can just ignore it but I have no way of knowing that it is a `POST` request. On Lollipop I am ignoring it just fine and everything is working great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Java API for that. If it's a form you're trying to modify you could just use JavaScript to rewrite it so that it doesn't post anywhere.